# How to count grouping records in JasperReports

Tags: jasper-reports, reporting

I have a problem with *JasperReports*.
I want to count the group, for example report data:

```
Item Movement 

No Product Name  DOC      Date       In    OUT    Saldo
**1**  Product_name_1                               0
                 DOC-0001 12-06-2013 2      0       2
                 DOC-0002 12-06-2013 2      0       4

**2**  Product_name_2                               0
                 DOC-0003 13-06-2013 2      1       1

**3**  Product_name_3                               0
                 DOC-0004 14-06-2013 1      0       1
```

I'm using *iReport Designer 5.1.0*.
Can someone help me to make **1** **2** **3** like the report?

Comment: In your example data, what do you want to count? What do you consider to be a group? Why isn't the `**1**` labeling enough?

Comment: Show us your JRXML or tell us what grouping bands you have in this report.